# thrust:: how to do this case of selective copy

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am using thrust to generate some random permutations on the GPU as follows:

```
// Compute a random list on CPU
int iterations = 500;
int src_size = 2048;
thrust::host_vector<int> cpu_rand_list (iterations * 4);

for(size_t i = 0; i < cpu_rand_list.size(); ++i) {
    cpu_rand_list[i] = src_size * (rand()/(1.0 + RAND_MAX));
}

// Copy the random list to GPU
thrust::device_vector<int> gpu_rand_list = cpu_rand_list;
```

Now the `gpu_rand_list` contains integer of some indexes and I have another array like:

```
thrust:;device_vector<float> values(2048);
// These are now filled with some values
...
```

What i would like to do is create another list which would only contain entries from `gpu_rand_list` which correspond to entries in `values` not equal to -1. So in CPU code something like:

```
std::vector<int> refined;
for (int i = 0; i < gpu_rand_list.size(); ++i) {
    if (values[gpu_rand_list[i]] != -1)
        refined.push_back(gpu_rand_list[i]);
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this in thrust? I tried to use the copy_if construct but could not make it work with these multiple arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thrust::copy_if (specifically [the stencil version](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html#ga36d9d6ed8e17b442c1fd8dc40bd515d5), I would think) is a reasonable starting point.  The only other complexity I see seems to be the indexing "through" `gpu_rand_list`.  This can be accomplished with a [permutation iterator](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide).

(aside: using a `float` array for the stencil when you want to do an exact comparison to -1 seems a little odd to me, but perhaps it makes sense.)

Something like this may work for you:

```
$ cat t881.cu
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

int main(){

// Compute a random list on CPU
  int iterations = 500;
  int src_size = 2048;
  thrust::host_vector<int> cpu_rand_list (iterations * 4);

  for(size_t i = 0; i < cpu_rand_list.size(); ++i) {
    cpu_rand_list[i] = src_size * (rand()/(1.0 + RAND_MAX));
    }

// Copy the random list to GPU
  thrust::device_vector<int> gpu_rand_list = cpu_rand_list;
  thrust::device_vector<float> values(src_size, -1.0f);
// pick some values to copy
  values[2] = 0;  values[3] = 0; values[5] = 0;
  thrust::device_vector<int> result(iterations * 4);

  thrust::copy_if(gpu_rand_list.begin(), gpu_rand_list.end(),thrust::make_permutation_iterator(values.begin(), gpu_rand_list.begin()), result.begin(), _1 != -1.0f);
  std::vector<float> h_values(src_size);
  thrust::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), h_values.begin());
  thrust::host_vector<int> h_result = result;
  std::vector<int> refined;
  for (int i = 0; i < cpu_rand_list.size(); ++i) {
    if (h_values[cpu_rand_list[i]] != -1)
        refined.push_back(gpu_rand_list[i]);
    }
  for (int i = 0; i < refined.size(); i++) 
    if (refined[i] != h_result[i]) { std::cout << "mismatch at: " << i << "was: " << h_result[i] << "should be: " << refined[i] << std::endl; return 1;}
    else std::cout << refined[i] << std::endl;
  return 0;

}
$ nvcc -o t881 t881.cu
$ ./t881
2
5
5
$
```

(I'm using [thrust placeholders](https://thrust.github.io/doc/namespaceplaceholders.html) so I don't have to create an explicit functor for the copy_if operation.)